Shouldn't `optical fibre` and `fiber optics` be synonyms?
There are seemingly identical tags:

optical-fibre
fiber-optics

But you need 2500 rep to suggest that these are synonyms. (I am years away from achieving that I think!)
Would anyone with appropriate reputation want to make these synonyms?

Thanks for pointing this out! I've merged the two tags (I chose optical-fibre as the master since it was used on more questions and someone had bothered to write up a tag wiki for it). I also merged fibre with optical-fibre.
Tag synonym suggestions are useless in practice since no one pays attention to them (so they are never approved). It is much more effective to make these requests on meta (as you have done) in order to bring it to the attention of the community, and moderators can most easily make the changes as we do not require others to approve of the action.
